# Getting descendents of certain name that aren't nested within elements of that name

Tags: jquery, nodes

I'm trying to obtain the top-most nodes of a given name, i.e. that aren't nested within other nodes of that name.

I'm trying to do it with the following, which is not working:

```
$(xmldoc).find("idea:not(:parent > idea)")
```

Comment: I think you can use `.children()` instead of find(), I'm sure that only returns the top level of items. Something like `$(xmldoc).children(".node_of_a_given_name");`

Comment: It doesn't return the top-most items, it only _searches_ the top level.  This isn't suitable because the nodes I'm seeking can be nested anywhere deeply in the DOM structure.  It's not the nodes at the top of the structure I'm seeking but the top-most nodes of that particular name.

Comment: Seems idea:not(idea idea) might be the answer...

Comment: so your xml is something like this? <idea a><idea></idea><idea></idea><idea></idea></idea> <idea b><idea></idea><idea></idea><idea></idea></idea> (where a and b are the nodes you want)